# Spring error: IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed and getOutputStream() has already been called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have got an error when I try to download a zipped file using Spring boot and spring MVC:
Errors:

> - SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed] with root cause
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
> - SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Basically, my app is loading a file, zipping it and download the new zip file.

This is my application Controller:

```js
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    public String fileZipped;
    public String inputFile;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/uploadForm")
    public String provideUploadInfo() {
        return "uploadForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/")
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                   HttpServletResponse downloadResponse) {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                inputFile = file.getOriginalFilename();
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(new File(Application.UPLOAD_DIR + "/" + inputFile)));
                FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), stream);
                stream.close();
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                        "You successfully uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!");
                FileUtils.copyDirectory(Application.UPLOAD_DIR, Application.OUTPUT_FOLDER);
                FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(Application.UPLOAD_DIR));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                        "You failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " => " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " because the file was empty");
        }

        return "redirect:/zipFiles";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/download")
    public String handleFileDownload(HttpServletResponse downloadResponse) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            if ( fileZipped!=null && Files.exists(Paths.get(fileZipped))) {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileZipped);
                downloadResponse.setContentType(fileZipped);
                downloadResponse.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Paths.get(fileZipped).getFileName().toString());
                outStream = downloadResponse.getOutputStream();
                org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outStream);
                downloadResponse.flushBuffer();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
            if (outStream != null) outStream.close();
        }
        return "redirect:/uploadForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/zipFiles")
    public String handleFileZip() throws IOException {
        if(inputFile!=null) {
            fileZipped = zipFiles(Application.OUTPUT_FOLDER, inputFile);
        }
        return "redirect:/download";
    }

    private String zipFiles(String folder, String zipFileName) throws IOException {

        String zipFile =  folder + "/" + FilenameUtils.removeExtension(zipFileName) + ".zip";
        FileOutputStream fileOutputstream = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputstream));

        File []filesArray = new File(folder).listFiles();
        for (File file : filesArray){
            if (!FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getAbsolutePath()).equals("zip")) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()));
                int length;
                while ((length = fileInputStream.read()) > 0) {
                    zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
                fileInputStream.close();
            }
        }
        zipOutputStream.close();
        return zipFile;
    }
```

I do no know why that is happening if I am closing the input and output streams.

Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: You cannot stream something and afterwards redirect. You either stream the result or redirect but not both. Basically your download  method is wrong.

Comment: That's the way the Servlet spec works. You need to find out if you need to redirect before anything gets flushed. So you cannot send a file +  a redirect. You can do only  one or the other.

Comment: Thanks @Augusto . I have modified the download method to: public void handleFileDownload... and it works (no errors) and the app stays in the uploadForm view (http://localhost:8080/uploadForm). But now I do not understand why the app stays in this view (http://localhost:8080/uploadForm) instead of in the last redirect view (http://localhost:8080/download).

Comment: Thanks to @M.Deinum as well!

Comment: how do I load again the uploadForm view?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the redirect. Instead of

```
return "redirect:/uploadForm";
```

return the view name.

```
return "/uploadForm";
```

Comment: thanks @ShankarPS, I had already tried that. The problem is as M. Deinum said, I can do only one thing, either stream or redirect.

Comment: return null; fixed the problem for me